# Object file addressing in Linux Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, kbuild

I am writing a simple device driver in Linux. In the makefile we normally write first line as

```
obj-m += hello.o
```

where `hello` is the module written. I have seen in other makefiles the symbol `+=` being replaced by `:=` and some others. What is significant difference between the two and also what are the possible options?

Comment: If you read the documentation for the `make` program, it will tell you exactly what the meaning of `:=` or `+=` means in the makefile. See for example the [GNU Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/).

Comment: Ya sure will go through it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Kbuild resets `obj-m` along with some other variables (see [scripts/Makefile.build](http://lxr.linux.no/linux/scripts/Makefile.build)) before including user Makefile, so there is no difference between `+=` and `:=` assignments (assuming that there is the only `hello.o` line).

Personally I would prefer appending assignment (`+=`). This prevents some stupid errors like the following:

```
obj-m := hello.o
obj-m := world.o
```

If the last line is a copy-paste of the first one and you forget to change the assignment type to `+=`, then you'll get only `world.o` compiled (without `hello.o`).

I would also suggest you to read Kbuild documentation about [how to write module makefiles](http://lxr.linux.no/linux/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt).

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thank you very much. Will get back if any doubts come up.